# Where can I buy replacement stickers for the set 8018?

Tags: stickers, replacement-parts

I need replacement stickers for set 8018. I've bought a used set and I'd like to change around the sticker position.

Answer (score 1):

You can get replacement stickers on BrickLink. Here is the link to the 8018 stickers: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=8018stk01